# Add Custom right click in interact.js drag items

Tags: jquery, interact.js

I would to add custom right click "Send to Front" and "Send to back" in the draggable items.

**HTML**

```
<div id="drag-1" class="draggable">
  <p> You can drag one element </p>
</div>
<div id="drag-2" class="draggable">
    <p> with each pointer </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#drag-1, #drag-2 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 6.5em;
  margin: 10%;

  background-color: #29e;
  color: white;

  border-radius: 0.75em;
  padding: 4%;

  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
          transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}

#drag-me::before {
  content: "#" attr(id);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

For Reference : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KabeerRifaye/znqk6geg/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see it working here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zanon/h8pgbr12/1/)

*Send to front* or *Send to back* can be easily implemented changing the `z-index` of the elements. The element with the greater `z-index` value will be on top.

E.g.: sending `#element1` on top of `#element2`:

```
$('#element1').css('z-index', 2);
$('#element2').css('z-index', 1);
```

Note that both elements must have the `position` CSS attribute to `absolute`, `fixed` or `relative`. I've used `position: relative;` (read more [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/)).

To implement the context menu, there are dozens of plugins available. I've used the nice [jQuery contextMenu from medialize](https://github.com/medialize/jQuery-contextMenu).

To use it, after loading the JS libraries (see the external references that I've added), use:

```
$(function(){
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-one', // I've added this class to the element
        callback: function(key, options) {
            // change the z-index values based on "key" value
        },        
        items: {
            "front": {name: "Send to front"},
            "back": {name: "Send to back"}
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah. It's great for 2-3 items. What's the solution If I'm using **ng-repeat** for showing the more no of divs (say 10-15).